# What are legitimate reasons for a program to need access to /proc/self/mem?

Tags: process

I have noticed that both browsers Firefox and Chromium on Linux do open the file `/proc/self/mem` for reading. No other program on my system reads this file, as far as I can tell.

`/proc/self/mem` is notorious for being vector for endless privilege escalation exploits, where usually memory is overwritten with malicious code and the program execution is hijacked.

This is even more sad, since browsers are the most exposed programs, with the most attack surface, because they take in untrusted input from the internet.

Is there a legitimate reason, why modern browsers need to read `/proc/self/mem`?

Comment: https://offlinemark.com/2021/05/12/an-obscure-quirk-of-proc/

Comment: "open the file /proc/self/mem for _reading_" " endless privilege escalation exploits, where usually memory is _overwritten_" So is there a problem?

Comment: I googled "what is /proc/self/mem" and got the link in the top comment. That appears to provide your answer. And since this appears to be a Linux kernel basics question, and not a security question, I'm migrating.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Browsers such as Firefox and Chromium use multiple processes, notably to *reduce* their attack surface. One aspect of this split into multiple processes is error handling: if a serious error occurs in a given process, it’s best to handle it in another process (because the crashed process may not be in a state compatible with allowing it to analyse itself, and to avoid a crashed process being owned).

So browsers keep handles open to `/proc/self/mem` so that they can pass those handles around, allowing a crash-handling process to read the memory of a crashed process, or a profiling process to read the memory of a process being profiled. This is used in particular for stack unwinding; see [the Perfetto documentation for details](https://perfetto.dev/docs/design-docs/heapprofd-design#service-operation) (this is the unwinder used in Chromium).